# AngularJS how to get multiple values on drop-down menu change value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a small angularjs function that gets the meeting id value of a drop down menu on its change event. The meeting name is used as the display value.

The values of the drop down come from an array that is populated on page load.

I now need to also get 2 more values from the array to later use in the code.

I am trying to add the variable assignment sort of following the same way that I did for meeting id, but I am getting nowhere, the values are not assigned.

This is the function:

```
$scope.GetValue = function (meeting) {
    
    $scope.meetingId = $scope.selectedMeeting;
    
    $scope.meetingName = $.grep($scope.MeetingList, function (meeting) {

        // These are the 2 new variables
        meeting.MeetingDate == $scope.meetingDate;
        meeting.MeetingTitle == $scope.meetingTitle;

        return meeting.MeetingID == $scope.meetingId;
    })[0].MeetingName;

    console.log("Selected MeetingID: " + $scope.meetingId + "\nSelected Meeting Date - Title: " + $scope.meetingName + + "\nSelected Meeting Title: " + $scope.meetingTitle + "\nSelected Meeting Date: " + $scope.meetingDate);    $scope.GetValue = function (meeting) {
    
    $scope.meetingId = $scope.selectedMeeting;
    
    $scope.meetingName = $.grep($scope.MeetingList, function (meeting) {

        // These are the 2 new variables
        meeting.MeetingDate == $scope.meetingDate;
        meeting.MeetingTitle == $scope.meetingTitle;

        return meeting.MeetingID == $scope.meetingId;
    })[0].MeetingName;

    console.log("Selected MeetingID: " + $scope.meetingId + "\nSelected Meeting Date - Title: " + $scope.meetingName + + "\nSelected Meeting Title: " + $scope.meetingTitle + "\nSelected Meeting Date: " + $scope.meetingDate);
}; 
};
```

This is the HTML, I am including it just to show how I get the values in the drop-down

```
                    <label for="meeting-list">Current Available Meetings</label>
                    <select ng-model="selectedMeeting" ng-change="GetValue()" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || !email" >
                        <option ng-repeat="meeting in MeetingList" value="{{meeting.MeetingID}}">Meeting: {{meeting.MeetingName}}</option>
                        <option value="">--Select Meeting--</option>
                    </select>
```

COuld it be possible to get some help to make this addition correctly?

Thank you,
Erasmo.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue with the usage of [`$.grep`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) in your code.
It can not modify the element parameter (here `meeting`), but it will filter and return the matched elements.

Also not sure if you aren't mis-spelling variable names (case-sensitive in JS !!) `MeetingName`, `MeetingTitle`,, `MeetingDate` and `MeetingID`. In your scope they all have initial lower-case.

You can use JavaScripts [`filter()` method on your array](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-array-filter/) to get the selected meeting.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
 .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope)  {    
    $scope.meetings = [
    { id: 1, title: 'First', date: '2020-09-01' }, 
    { id: 2, title: 'Second', date: '2020-09-02' }, 
    { id: 3, title: 'Third', date: '2020-09-03' }
    ];
    
    $scope.meetingIdSelected = $scope.meetings[0].id;

    $scope.pickMeeting = function() {
      console.log("selected",$scope.meetingIdSelected);
      $scope.selectedMeeting = $scope.meetings.filter(function (m) {
        return m.id === $scope.meetingIdSelected;
      })[0];
      console.log("found",$scope.selectedMeeting);
        };    
}]);
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <select ng-model='meetingIdSelected' ng-change="pickMeeting()" required ng-options='m.id as m.title for m in meetings'></select>
  <hr>
  selected:
  <tt>{{selectedMeeting}}</tt><br />
</div>

</body>
```